# DELETE Request can't read id in url

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm building a MEAN Stack application and I'm trying to add a delete for reservations to my application.

```
router.delete('/api/reservaties/:reservatie', auth, function (req, res, next) {
    Reservatie.remove({
        _id: req.reservatie._id
    }, function (err, reservatie) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({
            message: 'Reservatie deleted'
        });
    });
});
```

I've used it before like this without any problems. But now for some odd reason, "req.reservatie" is undefined.

This is the function in my service which calls for the http delete:

```
function deleteReservatie(reservatie) {
        return $http.delete('/api/reservaties/' + reservatie._id, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken()
            }
        }).success(function (res) {
          return res.data;
        }).error(function (error){
          //Handle error
        });
    }
```

Can't seem to find a solution. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `_id: req.reservatie` in your nodeJS function  ?

Comment: if you want to use this params :reservatie, you should do _id: req.params.reservatie

Comment: _id:req.params.reservatie worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem was using

```
_id: req.params.reservatie
```

instead off

```
_id: req.reservatie._id
```